# How to authenticate wsdl using Intellij's "Generate Java Code from WSDL" window?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wsdl

I am trying to use Intellij Idea to generate some java classes from a wsdl url which requires authentication. I have tried everything in the said "Generate Java Code from WSDL" window but the only option where I can actually click OK is using Apache Axis (because it is the only option where there is a user/pass to be filled), but then I receive "Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://example.com/basic?wsdl" even though I am passing a valid user/password (tried it on the browser and it works).

Everything else than Apache Axis, a red message saying "WSDL url is not valid" is showed and the OK button is kept disabled.

What else can I try to generate the classes I need?

Thanks.

Comment: same here - did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Generate classes using a maven plugin, see plenty of examples here: https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools-example , there are many more, but cxf-codegen-plugin should be all you need.